# Python - pywinauto - warnings

Tags: python, warnings, pywinauto

**Situation**

With the below code I'm getting some sort of weird **Warning** during run time, however, the script runs perfectly fine.

The warning prints after this line:

```
app.ChoosePage.Ok.Click()
```

This is the warning:

```
WARNING! Cannot retrieve text length for handle = <pywinauto.controls.win32_controls.DialogWrapper object at 0x0568C6D0>
```

**Question**

Is there a way to prevent this **Warning** from printing?

**Attempts**

I've tried using the below to no avail:

```
pywinauto.actionlogger.disable()
## OR
pywinauto.actionlogger.set_level(30)
```

Comment: Might be helpful if you told us what app, ChoosePage, Ok, and Click actually are.  As your question stands it's just a meaningless sequence of undefined terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to disable such warnings yet. Probably in your case dialog is already closed when pywinauto trying to get its caption. This warning also may raise when app doesn't respond. It assumed to be very rare case.

I moved it from plain `print()` function to `actionlogger` stuff. So it will be disabled by default in pywinauto 0.5.2.